# Convert Choice field value into Date format using Calculated column

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I have a choice column in which choices are name of months. I want a calculated column which returns me the date format data.

```
Choice Column  |  Calculated Column  
-----------------------------------  
January        |  1-Jan-1990  
February       |  1-Feb-1990  
March          |  1-Mar-1990  
April          |  1-Apr-1990  
May            |  1-May-1990
```

Date and year can be anything but I want to sort this data month wise. If I use choice column to sort data it will sort it alphabetically. But I want to sort the data in Month wise.

Is there any formula that can convert my choice column value to date format.

I tried to use below formula but it did not worked.

```
=DATE(YEAR(1990),MONTH([Month]),DAY(1))
```

`Month` is the choice column.

Is there any other way? I have to use Choice column I don't have any other option.

Or is there any way using which I can use Date Time column type in which user only selects month?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by jslink.

1. Make one js file (ex. ViewMonth.js) and add following code:

**Replace your column name instead of MonthNum and month**

```
(function () 
{
    var monthctx = {};
    monthctx.Templates = {};
    monthctx.Templates.Fields = {

        "MonthNum": {
            "View": setmonth
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(monthctx);
})();

//Note: 0=January, 1=February etc
function setmonth(ctx) 
{
     var itemID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var date = new Date("1-" + ctx.CurrentItem["month"] + "-1999"); 
   return date.getMonth();
}
```

2. Upload js file to document library.
3. Edit list page and edit webpart property.
4. Add js server relative path with specific prefix

   > ~sitecollection/Shared Documents/ViewMonth.js
5. You can get month number in specified column and now you can sort
   with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
=MONTH( "January" )
```

will not return a value because SharePoint doesn't have a clue what you meant

You have to convert the Month TEXT to a valid Number (january=1 in SharePoint)

```
IF([column]="January" , 1 , [column]="Feb2" , 2 , ...
```

Comment: Is there any other way, using which I can sort Choice column value date wise? In C# using code?

Comment: With c# you can program anything you want. this is a SharePoint forum, not c#